# Is conditional includes depending on the current page a good practise?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, include, conditional-statements

In my website, the current user retrieved in each page_load has lots of dependencies (13 in total) :

```
public User Get(Guid userId)
{
        MyEntities entities = _contextManager.Context;

        User user = entities.Users
            .Include(x => x.Something1)
            .Include(x => x.Something2)
            .Include(x => x.Something3)
            .Include(x => x.Something4)
            .Include(x => x.Something5)
            .Include(x => x.Something6)
            .Include(x => x.Something7)
            .Include(x => x.Something8)
            .Include(x => x.Something9)
            .Include(x => x.Something10)
            .Include(x => x.Something11)
            .Include(x => x.Something12)
            .Include(x => x.Something13.Select(s => s.Something14))
            .SingleOrDefault(u => (u.Id == userId));

        return user;
}
```

But it takes sooo long time that it is just no possible to keep it like that.
However, I don't need all those related objects in every single page.
Consequently, I thought I could do something like :

```
public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        App.GetCurrentUser(this);
    }
}
```

And in GetCurrentUser :

```
public static void GetCurrentUser(System.Web.UI.Page page)
{
    // Here only load data required by the current page
}
```

Is this a bad practise ?
If it is, is there any proper solution to make a query with lots of includes speeder ?

Thanks a lot !

***EDIT***

Here is the current App.GetCurrentUser :

```
public static User GetCurrentUser()
{
    using (UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork())
    {
        if (Membership.GetUser() != null)
        {
            UserRepo userRepo = new UserRepo();

            Guid guid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
            User user = userRepo.Get(guid); // the function with the 13 includes

            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a method outside of the page fetching the object in the first place if it doesn't know how to fetch the object in a generic way?  If each page has to perform a different query, then have each page perform their own different query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It is generic and working, but it is too long because the query loads every dependance even if the current page doesn't need it. I updated the first post to show the current method (which calls the function with the 13 includes)

Comment: Yes, and since you want each page to have its own set of includes, have each page have its own query where it writes out all of the includes that it'll need.  Done.  You're generalizing a query to be called from multiple places that *have different requirements as to what the query should do*.  Re-using the same query is something that you should be doing when *you actually want the same query*.

Comment: So should I have a GetUserForPage1(), GetUserForPage2(), and so on ?

Comment: Just have each page write its own query.  There's no point in creating a separate generalized query manager if it has no value to add.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for helping me :) Could you please post your answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you have so little work involved in this query being duplicated between your various pages, there's simply no need to generalize the query such that each page can call this one method.  Just have each page perform its own query, performing the includes that it needs.